# Mule ESB licensing - Using Mule ESB community run-time within integration product

Tags: licensing, mule

Can we use Mule ESB community run-time within our own integration product and redistribute it as closed source?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing issues. Not a practical programming problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please read through the following license

http://opensource.org/licenses/CPAL-1.0

http://www.mulesoft.org/licensing-mule-esb

The following might give you some more ideas..

[CPAL Mule licence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914647/cpal-mule-licence?rq=1)

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: better to sum up in  a plain english.